# How do I open multiple windows when Outlook 2010 starts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

**OS**: Windows 7 64-bit  **App**: Outlook 2010 32-bit  **Server**: Exchange 2010

I'd like to modify Outlook's default startup behavior so that it shows both my Inbox and Calendar when I click my shortcut.

I use both of them all day, and know how to just right-click the calendar and select "Open in New Window."  I run my inbox on one screen and my calendar on another.

I also configured my calendar to be the folder that opens by default when I start Outlook so I don't miss early appointments, but if I could somehow have BOTH open in two separate windows, that would be awesome.  Is there a command-line interface or something that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite easy. Just create a batch file, say **Outlook.cmd** (this is just a plain text file with .cmd extension instead of .txt, so you can use Notepad to edit it) on your Desktop with the following content (just copy-paste it):

```
@start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe" /select outlook:Inbox
@start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe" /select outlook:Calendar
```

After that run this file instead of Outlook shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

After you have right-clicked and "open in new window" you have more than one Outlook window open.

The trick is to FILE > EXIT when you leave Outlook. That way, Outlook "remembers" that you had multiple windows open and will open both the next time you start Outlook.

Comment: This is a great workaround, but the batch file approach guarantees both windows every time, even if I forget and close them one at a time using the close button on the upper right corner of the window.  Since I have been doing that habitually with every application for something like 20 years, I prefer not to try and break that habit now.  This IS a great tip for people that don't want to mess with a batch file, though!

Answer (score 0):

With both the Mail (inbox) and Calendar windows open when exiting Outlook, close the mail window first, then close the calendar window last.  Outlook will remember the next time you open and will open both windows.  However, if your machine is rebooted while Outlook is still open (sometimes sysadmin forces a reboot while you may not be at your desk), only your Inbox will be opened when you restart. You then have to manually reopen your calendar.