# How to open new window of Outlook 2013 with separate views

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

Ok... Here's my desire. I found it is possible to open multiple windows when Outlook starts from this answer:

[How do I open multiple windows when Outlook 2010 starts?](https://superuser.com/questions/358743/how-do-i-open-multiple-windows-when-outlook-2010-starts)

But here's what I am wanting to do:

I work daily on two fairly large screens where I keep everything I use windows. My desire is to have a "minimal" inbox view on the second screen so I can just see what's new and a 2-line preview of those messages in the inbox view. On the other screen, I keep Outlook maximized with the preview pane turned on, the 2-line previews disabled, and the side navigation bars are opened. In otherwords, I'm using the second screen's minimal window as more or less a "widget" to keep an eye on things when my primary screen is occupied by other stuff throughout the day. Is this possible? Or should I just look for a widget to accomplish this? (I prefer not to use a widget as I am trying to keep the other programs that run to a minimum)